# Expanding Joint probability distribution function having dependent random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, cumulative-distribution-function, joint-distribution

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ denotes two dependent random variables defined as
\begin{align}
Z_1&=\frac{XY}{aX+bY+c}\\
Z_2&=\frac{XY}{uX+vY+w}
\end{align} 
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameters $2\sigma_x^2$ and $2\sigma_y^2$ respectively. Further more $a$, $b$, $c$, $u$, $v$, and $w$ are finite non-zero positive real constants.

I'm evaluating
\begin{align}
Pr\{\min(Z_1,Z_2)\leq\eta\}
&=\underbrace{\Pr\{Z_1\leq\eta,Z_1\leq Z_2\}}_{P_1}+\underbrace{\Pr\{Z_2\leq\eta,Z_2\leq Z_1\}}_{P_2}\\
\end{align}
Both $P_1$ and $P_2$ will follow the same approach of evaluation. So evaluating $P_1$ as
\begin{align}
P_1 &= \Pr\{Z_1\leq\eta,Z_1\leq Z_2\}\\
&=\Pr\bigg\{\frac{XY}{aX+bY+c}\leq\eta,\frac{XY}{aX+bY+c}\leq\frac{XY}{uX+vY+w}\bigg\}\\
&=\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{bY\eta+c\eta}{Y(1-a\eta)},X\leq\frac{(b-u)Y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)},X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy\tag{1}
\end{align}

How can I expand $(1)$ for further evaluation?

> **This is what I've tried**

Defining event $A: X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}$ and $B:X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}$ and using the identity given in $(2)$
\begin{equation}
\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Hence form $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
\begin{align}
P_1=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\bigg[&\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\bigg\}+\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}\\
&-\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\cap X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}\bigg]f_Y(y)dy
\end{align}
Expanding integral
\begin{align}
P_1&=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy+\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy\\
&-\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\Pr\bigg\{X\leq\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\cap X\leq\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy
\end{align}
Rewriting in terms of cdf
\begin{align}
P_1&=\underbrace{\int_{y=0}^{\infty}F_X\bigg(\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\bigg)f_Y(y)dy}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{y=0}^{\infty}F_X\bigg(\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg)f_Y(y)dy}_{I_2}
\\&-\underbrace{\int_{y=0}^{\infty}F_{XX}\bigg\{\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\cap \frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy}_{I_3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

Evaluating integrals $I_1$, $I_2$ are simple, but not sure about $I_3$.

---

Further update 
The integrand in $I_3$ can be written as
\begin{align}
I_3 &= \int_{y=0}^{\infty}F_{XX}\bigg\{\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)}\cap \frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}F_{X}\bigg\{\min{\bigg(\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)},\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}}\bigg)\bigg\}f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=0}^{\min{\big(\frac{by\eta+c\eta}{y(1-a\eta)},\frac{(b-u)y+(c-w)}{v-a}}\big)}f_X(x)dxf_Y(y)dy
\end{align}